# leaflet, generate continuous coordinates based on a Polyline

Tags: leaflet

I don’t have detailed latitude and longitude data, I hope to automatically generate continuous latitude and longitude coordinates based on the two points.

On the one hand, there is the need for animation effects, such as driving the position of the icon according to the height of the mouse sliding.

For example, I have a `polyline` like this:

```
polylineData: [
          { lat: 36.181681, lon: 121.913284 },
          { lat: 23.804980, lon: 127.497168}]
```

Are there any plugin or calculation formulas that can help me generate continuous coordinates from point `{ lat: 36.181681, lon: 121.913284 }` to point `{ lat: 23.804980, lon: 127.497168}`

```
polylineData: [
              { lat: 36.181681, lon: 121.913284 },
              { lat: 36.171212, lon: 121.922323 },
                       .
                       .
                       .
              { lat: 23.121631, lon: 127.334284 },
              { lat: 23.804980, lon: 127.497168 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Libraries [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) or [GeometryUtil](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil) is very helpful.

You can calculate the latlng between two points and the distance
[destinationOnSegment](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destinationOnSegment)

or interpolate on the line: [interpolateOnLine](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#interpolateOnLine)

Example:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    var result = L.GeometryUtil.interpolateOnLine(map, poly, i); // between 0 and 1
    marker.setLatLng(result.latLng)
  i += 0.001;
},10);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/5gy8hmfu/

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of `GeometryUtil`,
I don’t know how to get started, there is not much explanation on the doc.

Comment: It's work thx.Your `jsfiddle` example is very helpful.